# Remove duplicated functions inside different if within a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function :

```
function __throwError(func) {
  if (func.length === 1) {
    function passNumber() {
      func(0);
    }
    function passString() {
      func("item");
    }
    function passEmptyArray() {
      func([]);
    }
    function passUndefinedOrNull() {
      func(undefined || null);
    }
    expect(passNumber).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
    expect(passString).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
    expect(passEmptyArray).toThrowError("The array is empty");
    expect(passUndefinedOrNull).toThrowError("The parameter is null or undefined");
  }
  if (func.length === 2) {
    function passNumber() {
      func(0, 1);
    }
    function passString() {
      func("item", 1);
    }
    function passEmptyArray() {
      func([], 1);
    }
    function passUndefinedOrNull() {
      func(undefined || null, 1);
    }
    expect(passNumber).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
    expect(passString).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
    expect(passEmptyArray).toThrowError("The array is empty");
    expect(passUndefinedOrNull).toThrowError("The parameter is null or undefined");
  }
}
```

You may notice that there are duplicated `passNumber`,`passString`,`passEmpty` inside different `if` statements and each function call different `callback` function `func`.

How do I remove duplicated functions: `passNumber`,`passString`,`passEmpty` and just have once call with different parameters ?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? There seems to be no point to this code? If you have `(func.length === 3) ` can you provide it?

Comment: @konijn, I've never passed more then 2 parameters in a function.

Comment: Shouldn't `expect(passString).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array")` be `expect(passString).toThrowError("The parameter should be a sting")` ("a string" instead of "an array")?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the two parts is that the second part has an additional parameter `1`? You can provide an array with the original param, if function.length is 2, push `1` into it. the just call `func.apply(null, params)`.

Here is a solution base on the idea:

````
function __throwError (func) {
  const testcases = [
    new TestCase(func, 0, 'The parameter should be an array'),
    new TestCase(func, 'item', 'The parameter should be an array'),
    new TestCase(func, [], 'The array is empty'),
    new TestCase(func, undefined, 'The parameter is null or undefined'),
    new TestCase(func, null, 'The parameter is null or undefined')
  ];
  if (func.length === 2) {
    testcases.forEach(testcase => testcase.value.push(1));
  }
  for (const testcase of testcases) {
    expect(testcase.fn).toThrowError(testcase.errMsg);
  }
}

class TestCase {
  constructor (testFn, value, errMsg) {
    this.value = [value];
    this.errMsg = errMsg;
    this.testFn = testFn;
  }
  fn () {
    this.testFn.apply(null, this.value);
  }
}
```
````